# How to do an outer join with full result between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

**TABLE1**

```
id_attr
-------
1
2
3
```

**TABLE2**

```
id  |  id_attr  | val
----------------------
10  |  1        | A
10  |  2        | B
```

As a result I want a table that show:

**RESULT**

```
id  |  id_attr  | val
----------------------
10  |  1        | A
10  |  2        | B
10  |  3        | NULL
```

So I want the row with id=10 and id_attr=3 also when id_Attr=3 is missing in TABLE2 (and I know that because I have a NULL value (or something else) in the val column of RESULT.

NB: I could have others ids in table2. For example, after insert this row on table2: {11,1,A}, as RESULT I want:

```
id  |  id_attr  | val
----------------------
10  |  1        | A
10  |  2        | B
10  |  3        | NULL
11  |  1        | A
11  |  2        | NULL
11  |  3        | NULL
```

So, for every id, I want always the match with all id_attr.

Comment: Why do you want result ID 10 for id_attr  3?

Comment: It's simply a customer requirement.

Comment: You should clarify your question if you have different ids.

Comment: Always 10, for all id_attr's not found in table2?

Comment: I have more than one id, I'm editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific example only has one `id`, so you can use the following:

```
select t2.id, t2.id_attr, t2.val
from table2 t2
union all
select 10, t1.id_attr, NULL
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id_attr = t1.id_attr);
```

EDIT:

You can get all combinations of attributes and ids in the following way.  Use a `cross join` to create all the rows you want and then a `left join` to bring in the data you want:

```
select i.id, t1.id_attr, t2.val
from (select distinct id from table2) i cross join
     table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = i.id and t2.id_attr = t1.id_attr;
```

Comment: No, my example is a sub-table of TABLE2, unfortunately I could have others value of table1.id, and in this case your query don't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you want to do just an outer join on id_attr instead of id.

```
select * from table2 t2
    left outer join table1 t1 on t2.id_attr = t1.id_attr;
```

Comment: No, executing your query I have 2 rows: [10,1,A],[10,1,B] but I want also [10,3,null]